# Changing windows layout close,minimize,maximize,menu keys

Tags: unity, 14.04, window, layout

I've searched out around and found out this useful tool named Unity Tweak, however once I try to change my key (close, minimize, maximize & menu) positions, nothing happens... Not sure if I'm the only one experiencing this, I was wondering if there's another way I could do this. I'm kinda new to ubuntu and this whole linux thing so please bear with me if my question seems a bit stupid, I installed ubuntu today, an hour ago...

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Known bug, apparently: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1309964 :( Please mark that bug as affecting you so that it gets more attention.

Answer (score 1):

There's another tool that should work the first time you try it. It's called the Gnome Tweak Tool. Just open a terminal (by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`. Follow the prompts, then look for it in the applications list once it's finished installing.